# MYSQL Replace data from another table

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a table with a column called Email
within this column the data contain multiable email address separated with ,
i would like to update this column with the ids from another table
table 2 Called users 
id, emailaddress
UPDATE orders SET email= REPLACE( email, ( SELECT id from users where users.email like order.email) );

how do i write this?
many thanks

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow the question as it's currently phrased, at least for me. Could you please share your tables' structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Table 1 <Users>
column is <email> with data like user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com
so i want to update from table2 <email address>
columns id,emailaddress
i want to update table 1 with the id from email address table.
i.e.  = 4,6
does this make more sence?